# jquery.append() Iframe IE Problem

Tags: jquery, iframe, append

Perhaps this is a bug, but I cannot access an outer document from an iframe with jquery (IE7).

here a very simple example:

top document:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="test2.html" id="UserIFrame" name="UserIFrame">
</body>
</html>
```

and child iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles/genevadesign_jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       function doit(){
          $('body',top.document).append($('#test'));
          $('#test',top.document).fadeIn(300);
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">test</div>
<input type="button" onclick="doit();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I try to access the top document from the inner frame like this:

$('body', top.document).append($('#test'));

But this does not work in IE7 "Invalid Argument". It works within the same document, but as soon as I refer another document it stops working.

PS. Gecko Browser can handle this. Just IE7 so far is not able to do so.

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises only in IE, and stems from the inability to create nodes and move nodes between the windows (which is surprisingly a good approach).

Consider the following example:

```
$("<iframe/>").append("<div/>");
```

In IE7 this will cause an error - as the element should have been created using `iframe.ownerWindow.document`, and not with `document.createElement` method, or `window.ownerDocument.createElement` method. And it's happening in every DOM manipulation methods. IE7 also doesn't support `importNode` / `adoptNode` methods.

So that leaves creating objects via JS and manipulating, yay!

Comment: Your answer help me to fix the problem with IE 7...
I use 
`iframe.ownerDocument.appendChild(form)`
and its work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

tries with "[window.parent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp)"

Comment: Yes, now I get no more errors but the <div> I wish to copy is still not in the outer frame.